# Is there a way to randomly bucket rows and have those buckets be similar values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have buckets of loans tagged in a table, dbo.loans. This table tags loans in the [loan_tag] field and sub-buckets in the [sub_bin] field. Now I am attempting to create sub-buckets with loans chosen at random but also having similar book values. I have no problem selecting/updating a new field using a query similar to below

I have no problem selecting/updating a new field using a query similar to below:

```
UPDATE DBO.LOANS SET SUB_BIN = "SUB-BUCKET2" WHERE CAPS_HEDGE IN ( SELECT TOP 10000 CAPS_HEDGE FROM DBO.LOANS WHERE SUB_BIN IS NULL AND LOAN_TAG = "PARENT_BUCKET" ORDER BY NEWID() )
```

If there are 50,000 records I can run this 5 times, changing the sub-bucket name each run.

What I need now is to make sure the individual buckets are of similar total book value, which is another field name in dbo.loans. By just running this 5 times it will give me 5 sub-buckets with an equal record count, but different and random book_values.

Does anybody know how I can accomplish this? Also, is there a way to have this run N amount of times and for all different parent bucket names?

Comment: without sample data and expected output, is not that easy understand what you want.

Comment: You can probably use `ntile()` with a random order to split up into buckets, but the similar book value requirement is harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a random bin with approximately equal book value, then sequentially assign a number to a book values and take each nth one:

```
with toupdate as (
      select l.*, row_number() over (order by book_value) as seqnum
      from loans l
     )
update toupdate
    set sub_bin = seqnum % 5;
```